# Rolling up rows and creating a new row per roll up

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `table` like this:

```
DepartmentName | SubDivisionName | Importance
Security       | Cyber           | 1
Security       | Airlines        | 2
Security       | Banks           | 3
Health         | Children        | 4
Health         | Elderly         | 5
Housing        | Housing         | 6
Misc           |                 | 7
```

I want to create a new `table` ( a temp table ) based off of that to look like this below. Notice that whenever we `GROUP BY DepartmentName` and number of its GROUP members is bigger than one, **it means that DepartmentName has some SubDivisions** so we want to insert a new row for **that  **and Importance value would get updated accordingly.

```
DepartmentName | SubDivisionName | Importance
Security       |                 | 1
Security       | Cyber           | 2
Security       | Airlines        | 3
Security       | Banks           | 4
Health         |                 | 5
Health         | Children        | 6
Health         | Elderly         | 7
Housing        | Housing         | 8
Misc           |                 | 9
```

I tried some GROUP BY to find the ones that have more than one record but still had trouble inserting new rows and correctly updating the `importance` column.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Have you tried using *union*?

Comment: @DaleK I have created a temp table from the ones that need an extra row but I am having trouble how to insert these new rows while still correctly updating the "Importance" value of the rows that come below them in the new table for example House row  is now 8 which used to be 6 originally

Comment: We need to *see* what you tried... add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following provide your expected results?

You can union your existing data with rows that have >1 DepartmentNames and then use *row_number* to provide the new sequence:

```
with u as (
    select DepartmentName, SubDivisionName, Importance 
    from t
    union all
    select DepartmentName, null, Min(Importance)
    from t
    group by DepartmentName
    having Count(*) > 1
)
select DepartmentName, SubDivisionName, 
  Row_Number() over(order by Importance, SubDivisionName) as Importance
from u
order by Importance;
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DWsO4__A)

Comment: In the over clause, why did we have to add SubDivisionName to the order by ? I noticed it won't work if I take it out but I didn't understand why it works with SubDivisionName

Comment: Because the unioned data duplicates the `Importance` value so you need a tie-breaker for the sort order.

Comment: wow you are really good at SQL :) I had spent maybe five hours on solving this today. But I am not good at Row_Number , Window functions so I was using WHILE loop lol with no success

Comment: I would recommend then to study the documentation and tutorials for window functions, [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event17/Window_Functions) is a respected font of knowledge